# Why isn't my java code proceeding past my if statements?

Tags: java, performance, debugging, methods, conditional-statements

Okay, I have never had this problem before so I am not sure how to word it or to repair it, I am building a java application that creates dealers, in that application I have the parameters passed in to the DealerFactory.createDealer method and proceed to first check if that dealer exists with a conditional statement that looks like this:

```
    if (DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getLoginId().equals(loginId)) {

        throw new Exception("Sorry That Dealer Already Exists");

    } else if (DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getId().equals(DNo)){

        throw new Exception("Sorry That Dealer Already Exists");

    } else {
         << proceed with the rest of the method here >>
```

I have seen this done before so as to check the availability of the username and the id of the person being created. However after running it I found that if I create the dealer and the condition evaluates to true the if statement works just fine letting me know that I have created a user that already exists and I need to create him/her with new a different Id and username. However if the condition evaluates to false I never seem to make it into the else portion of the statement, I am getting no errors, no compilation issues, and no exceptions I have written the statement differently to try that, which wasn't really any different it just looked syntactically different:

```
 if (DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getLoginId().equals(loginId)
            || DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getId().equals(DNo)) {

        throw new Exception("Sorry That Dealer Already Exists");
    }
```

I have included println statements to follow the program through its run and when the condition evaluates to false I never make it into the else statement. I cant seem to figure out why it is breaking on the condition statement when it is evaluated to false, any thoughts?

edit:::

Ok so that I can be of more assistance in helping you guys help me lol here is the method in its entirety, I apologize for not posting it in the first place

```
public static int create(String DNo, String name, String admin,
        String loginId, String password, String callSrc, String voiSys,
        String whoCall, String callBrt, String active, String adfEmail)
        throws SQLException, Exception {

    int validateResult = 0;


    if (DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getLoginId().equals(loginId)
            || DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getId().equals(DNo)) {

        throw new Exception("Sorry That Dealer Already Exists");
    }

        try {

            DealerFactory.pool = DBConnector.getInstance();
            DealerFactory.connect = DBConnector.getConnection();
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement = connect
                    .prepareStatement("Insert Into Dealers (DNo, Dealer, Admin, Login, Password, CallSrc, VoiSys, WhoC, CBrt, Active, ADFemail) "
                            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(1, DNo);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(2, name);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(3, admin);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(4, loginId);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(5, password);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(6, callSrc);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(7, voiSys);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(8, whoCall);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(9, callBrt);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(10, active);
            DealerFactory.preparedStatement.setString(11, adfEmail);

            validateResult = DealerFactory.preparedStatement
                    .executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            System.err.println("Error: " + ex + "\n");
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            DBUtils.closePrepStatement(DealerFactory.preparedStatement);
            DealerFactory.pool.freeConnection(DealerFactory.connect);

        }

    return validateResult;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId)` returns `null` if the dealer doesn't exists?? If not, what does it returns?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau yes it would return null, but with it being null wouldn't that push it to the next statement because it doesn't equal the current input? If I'm wrong the I will handle the null, but I have never had to deal with it before so I'm unsure

Comment: What type is `DNo` and what does it contain?

Comment: No it won't, it will throw a `NullPointerException` as nem says in his answer.

Comment: @RichardDavy No, it wouldn't if you call `.getLoginId()` on `null`.

Comment: @DirkLachowski DNo is a string and returns a string

Comment: Have you run through the code with a debugger and evaluated the expressions by hand? then you can see the results of every sub-expression. I cannot test it right now but it doesn't look too bad but I don't really get the intention of the first check. simply check if the result of your fetch is not null, then you already know that you have a duplicate.

Comment: Your method throws `Exception`, the `NullPointerException` is managed by the caller. Check if that happens. I suggest you create your own exception to avoid this kind of problem in the future or to have a method that returns a `Boolean` before calling `create` to check if you need to create the dealer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you shouldn't chain methods like that due to dangers of `NullPointerException`

So this part:

```
if(DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getLoginId().equals(loginId))
```

Could look something like this:

```
if(DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId) != null && 
   DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getLoginId().equals(loginId))
```

Or you could have a separate `null` check before all your `if` statements.

However, what you are doing is an overkill. This whole part:

```
DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getLoginId()
```

Returns `null` if you cannot find a dealer or `loginId` that you already have.
Assuming your `fetchDealer()` method returns `null` if dealer cannot be found.

Instead of:

```
if(DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId).getLoginId().equals(loginId)))
```

You can just do:

```
if(DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId) != null)
```

Another improvement you could do is to add a method to `DealerFactory` called `dealerExists(String id)` declared something like this:

```
boolean dealerExists(String id) {
    return (YOUR_DATA_STRUCTURE_OF_DEALERS.get(id) != null);
}
```

Or even:

```
boolean dealerExists(String id) {
    return (fetchDealer(loginId) != null);
}
```

This would allow for better logical flow of your code. Your `if` statement would be very clear then:

```
if(DealerFactory.dealerExists(loginId) {
    throw new Exception("Sorry That Dealer Already Exists");
}
```

Also, the value `DNo` is the dealer number I presume and you are checking if a dealer exists with the provided `loginId` or the provided `DNo`. However, in you checks you are comparing the `DNo` to the `loginId` to check if a dealer exists. What exactly is the point of `DNo` and shouldn't the `loginId` be enough to determine that the dealer exists?
If you really need to check the `DNo` as well, just add it as a check within the methods I suggested above.

Comment: I have no Idea why I didn't think of this in this manner, Why I was directly looking for their id and login made sense to me but this makes much more sense and reduces a lot of code that was un-necessary, thanks very much my friend.

Answer (score -1):

More information regrading the variables that you are passing into the conditional would be of great help, (i.e. `loginId` and `DNo`). The first thing I would do is simplify your conditions in the `if` & `else if` statements.

It seems like you could change the `if` conditional to be `if(DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId))` and have it work just the same since if the factory returns a dealer with the ID that you are looking for, that dealer already exists. From my understanding of what you're trying to achieve, it's unnecessary to dig any deeper. Also try running through this section of code with the debugger and monitor variables step-by-step to see what things look like at each line of code.

Edit:

You could also move the expressions outside of the conditional and set them to variables. For example:

```
int dealerId =  DealerFactory.fetchDealer(loginId);
if(dealerId != null && dealerId != loginId) {
      //<< proceed with the rest of the method here >>
} else {
     //<<throw exception>>
}
```

Checking to see if `dealerId` is null in the conditional would avoid `NullPointerException`s, and declaring things outside of the conditional will make it easier to debug by hand.

Comment: I just edited the post from its original version, I apologize for not doing so in the first place, the information that I gave was a little lacking